# How do I add Placement Constraint distanceInstance configuration in Ansible Playbook yaml

Tags: ansible, amazon-ecs

I am trying to add Placement Constraints **distanceInstance** to my current Ansible Playbook yaml for redundant **AWS ECS tasks** (2 tasks) to run on **different EC2 instances.**

While placing the **distanceInstance** configuration in Ansible yaml as below in *ecs_service*

```yaml
- name: Some task
  ecs_service:
    force_new_deployment: "yes"
    placement_constraints:
     - type: distinctInstance
```

I am getting these errors as below:

> An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: Invalid type for parameter placementConstraints[0].expression, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
>
> botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter placementConstraints[0].expression, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'str'>\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

I am expecting the **ECS deployment tab to show the distanceInstance as placement constraint** and to have the 2 tasks to run on different **AWS EC2 instances**.

Am I missing any configurations or any process to be followed in AWS before making such changes?

Comment: Your example is invalid because of indentation errors for the module parameters. It's impossible to know if this is a copy paster error or if it is the source of your actual error. Please fix your example and make sure your run it with the correct indentation and get the same error.

Comment: Thanks I have formatted the yaml code snippet

Comment: It looks like the module is expecting `expression` as a string even though the aws documentation specifies you should not provide it when `type: distinctInstance`. This looks like a bug. Did you try to specify it as an empty string (`expression: ""`) ? Moreover, did you check you are running the latest version of ansible / community.aws collection ?